# Wifi and Bluetooth is not working

Tags: networking

I have dual booted my PC with Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10.
Here in Ubuntu i am not able to enable either WiFi or Bluetooth.
On writing command `rfkill list` it shows:

```
0: phy0: wireless lan
               Soft blocked: NO
               Hard blocked: YES
```

Help how to fix.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: are you sure you installed the latest version of  drivers ?

Comment: @Fabby That solution is not useful, because there are so many hardware specific ways of fixing this.

Comment: @Pilot6 Close vote retracted.  :)